# External 12v power supply to relay

Tags: power-supply, relay

I have a 12v 8 channel relay https://www.modmypi.com/raspberry-pi/relays-and-home-automation-1032/relay-boards-1033/8-channel-12v-relay-module which I want to connect to my RPi3 so I need an external power supply.

I watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ur0w7VeLX08 which is useful for a newbie like me but the power supply has female connections
[image]

Do I need to / can I modify a supply myself to create one of these?  I can't seem to find anywhere to purchase one.

Comment: Obviously it's possible to make a PSU with a custom connector if you cannot buy one. I don't quite get the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just did a quick google search, you can combine perhaps something like this https://www.pololu.com/product/2449 (DC Barrel Jack to 2-Pin Terminal Block Adapter)

[image: DC jack to two pin]

and then grab two male-female jumper wires e.g. [Ebay](https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Male-To-Male-To-Female-To-Female-Jumper-Solderless-Wire-Dupont-Cable-Ribbon-Kit/232147132063)

[image: Jumper wires]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was thinking of just stripping the wires in a 12v power supply and soldering on to female jumper cables. Do you think that is OK or is the adaptor you shared performing some additional function?

Comment: Oh definitely DIY it it's just some electrons moving :) Since you used the word 'newbie' I assumed you might not have soldering equipment @StuartBrown

Comment: All the gear, no idea ;-). Seriously though, thanks for your help, I couldn't really find anything online about how to power it